# Fetching multiple things

Tags: javascript, fetch

Let' say we want to fetch three files. We can do this by:

```
fetch("./1.json")
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((text_1) => {
    fetch("./2.json")
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((text_2) => {
        fetch("./3.json")
          .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((text_3) => {
            console.log("Done")
        });
      });
  });
```

But this nesting will over complicatet the code. Are there any work-arounds for this?

They can all be fetched at the same time OR sequentially

Comment: Do you want to fetch all at the same time or sequentially?

Comment: It doesn't matter :)

Comment: I use `async` - `await` like crazy lately - I can no longer read "then"-ed code

Comment: Can you post your answer?

Comment: @BobCat it does matter, fetching all the data at the same time is usually faster

Comment: Q: What's the "text_1" etc. all about?  ANYWAY: you absolutely DON'T need to "nest" anything.  I was going to suggest [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) - but Phoenix1355 beat me to it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use Promises like so:

```js
Promise.all([
  fetch("./1.json").then((response) => response.json()),
  fetch("./2.json").then((response) => response.json()),
  fetch("./3.json").then((response) => response.json()),
]).then((values) => console.log(values));
```

It should log the responses as an array, e.g.:

```
["res1", "res2", "res3"]
```

Comment: okay but how do you get the data as a variable?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @BobCat I edited the answer to also include the data. It will be provided as the `values` parameter in the `.then`.

Answer (score 1):

If they need to be handled in series, you could create individual callbacks for each:

```js
const handleResponse1 = (text_1) =>
  fetch("./2.json").then(res => res.json()).then(handleResponse2);

const handleResponse2 = (text_2) =>
  fetch("./3.json").then(res => res.json()).then(handleResponse3);

const handleResponse3 = (text_3) => console.log("Done");

fetch("./1.json").then(res => res.json()).then(handleResponse1);
```

If you want all the responses simultaneously, you can destructure the `Promise.all` result.

```js
const requests = [
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3'
];

const fetchJson = async (request) =>
  fetch(request).then(response => response.json());

const fetchJsonAll = async (requests) =>
  Promise.all(requests.map(fetchJson));

(async () => {
  const [ res1, res2, res3 ] = await fetchJsonAll(requests)
    .catch(err => console.log(err.message));

  console.log(JSON.stringify(res1));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res2));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res3));
})();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  const allPromises = [fetch("./1.json"), fetch("./2.json"), fetch("./3.json")]
 
  Promise.all(allPromises).then((values) => {
    console.log(values);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a loop as well as `async`/`await`:

```js
async function fetchStuff() {
  const files = ["./1.json", "./2.json", "./3.json"];
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const result = (await fetch(files[i])).json();
  }
  console.log("Done");
}
fetchStuff();
```